# Can we use the same reduction L1 -> L2 for coL1 -> coL2

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

does L1 
  
    ≤
    p
  
 L2
yield that coL1 
  
    ≤
    p
  
coL2 for the same reduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If $f$ is a polynomial-time computable function such that $x \in L_1 \iff f(x) \in L_2$ then

$x \in \text{co}L_1 \iff x \not\in L_1 \iff f(x) \not\in L_2 \iff f(x) \in \text{co}L_2.
$